# Geocoding a location with a apostrophe in Apps Script gives an 'Action not allowed' error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-geocoding-api

I have the following code in a [Google Apps Script web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web):

```
Maps.newGeocoder().geocode("Tyson's Corner, VA");
```

Yes, there's a typo in there. I always forget the proper name of the place.

This code uses the [Apps Script Maps Geocoder to determine the location of the address](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder#geocode(String)).

When I run this minimal code, Apps Script raises an error:

> Action not allowed

When I remove the `'` from the address, the call completes and returns the correct location.

Does anyone know if this is expected behavior (I can't find it in the docs)?

Comment: I've tried your use case and experience the same error, I think there is an existing [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765336) for this scenario and still under investigation. You may want to follow it to be updated regarding any solutions or workaround (currently removing the "`'`" would let this work, which you've already did).

Comment: YES! That's indeed precisely the same. I have no idea why it didn't show up in any of my searches. Can you provide it as an answer? I think there's enough substance (with the link to the off-site bug tracker and your description) to be useful to future devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your use case and experience the same error, I think there is an existing [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765336) for this scenario and still under investigation. You may want to follow it to be updated regarding any solutions or workaround (currently removing the "`'`" would let this work, which you've already did).